# Count the number of clicks and return the browser url of clicked link in Selenium, Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm a beginner in Selenium, Python and trying to automate the banner testing using Python, Selenium Webdriver.

I want to record number clicks has made and after clicking need to check the URLs are landing to the correct page or not and I have to keep a delay of 5 secs for each click.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class slTest(unittest.TestCase):

def test_santi(self):
    self.browser=webdriver.Ie("C:\Users\chethan\Documents\IEDriverServer.exe")
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)
    self.browser.get("http://mywebsite.com/banners/")
    vr=self.browser.execute_script("return initValues")
    print vr
    num=0
    res=self.browser.find_element_by_id("productcontainer")
    links=res.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    for link in links:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,link.get_attribute("id"))))
        element.click()

        print link.get_attribute("id")
        #print self.browser.current_url
        num=num+1

    print num
    self.browser.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
unittest.main()
```

The value of num has to increase only on click and to record the URL which is loaded after click.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you need to do this in a more complex environment as opposed to a simple count-and-check function).

In that case, you should decorate selenium's click method:

```
clickMethod = getattr(selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement, 'click')
if clickMethod.func_name != 'decorated':
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        self.count += 1

        start_url = self.driver.current_url
        return_this = clickMethod(*args, **kwargs)

        ##
        # you should probably time.sleep() or use javascript to check that page is finished loading
        ##

        end_url = self.driver.current_url
        if end_url != start_url:
            self.clicked_url_list.append( end_url )

        return return_this

    setattr( selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement, 'click', decorated )
```

Comment: im a beginner, im not sure what you are saying, can you please elaborate bit more and how to use the above and also "setattr" where your calling this function.

Comment: setattr() is used to modify an attribute of a class, e.g. myClass.attribute.  The code above overwrites selenium's click method with a modified/decorated method that will do your counting and url checking stuff